# Sticky sidebar 20px top size

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

[image]

[TEST PAGE](https://stagingsvrs.sorensonaws.com/svrs_community_2019)

Im trying to have the top of the vertical line of the sidebar to stop at the top nav (example image attached), I tried to add `'top': '20'` in the js code and it didnt work. I also tried `margin-top: 20px` in CSS and that didnt do the trick. Im not sure where I can add 20px height above the sidebar.

---

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var length = $('#community-sidebar').height() - $('#community-section-col1').height() + $('#community-sidebar').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function () {

    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var height = $('#community-section-col1').height() + 'px';

    if (scroll < $('#community-sidebar').offset().top)  {

        $('#community-section-col1').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': '0'
        });

    } else if (scroll > length) {

        $('#community-section-col1').css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'bottom': '0',
            'top': 'auto'
        });

    } else {

        $('#community-section-col1').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'top': '0',
            'height': height
        });

    }
});

});
```

CSS

```
#community-sidebar {left: -45px; position: absolute; top: -40px; height: 1500px;}
.h-line { border-left: solid black 1px; height: 550px; border-width: thin; width: 1px; left: 189px; position: absolute; top: 0;}
```

Comment: `padding-top`??

Comment: I dont think that will work, because If I add `padding-top: 20px;` then the sidebar will move its position lower when the page loads. Im referring to when it scrolls to the top nav. It has to do with the code.

Comment: So add the padding when it scrolls to the top...no?

Comment: Yes something like that.

Comment: I think the top of the vertical link of the sidebar need to stop to the top nav instead of the month links. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the header with a div having height `20px` followed with `position:fixed` for the header.

```
<div style="height:20px">
  <div style="position:fixed">
    //your header content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where in the code? It will not work in CSS. The function needs to work to make the top vertical line to reach to the top nav.

Comment: You don't really need any javascript to achieve this. When you wrap the header in another element it means to put another element in the place of your header, and then to put your header inside of the new element in question. This refers to changing the default structure of your page, and is not meant to refer to an action which is to be executed at runtime.

But by doing this you will reserve 20px in the document, which will make it so all other content is displayed 20px lower, and will thus connect to the menu neatly in the default scroll position.

Comment: Samuel is right, we actually don't need js to achieve this. I will update the answer above with a code.

Comment: That didnt work for me - I put `<div style="height:20px; position: fixed;">` and the whole sidebar was off of its position.

Comment: Can you include the whole HTML for me to see what you're referring to.

Comment: See the test page and the source code with your code. It doesnt work.